# React - Slow keyboard input even with useMemo()

Tags: reactjs

I have this code which has plenty of inputs, one for each price value to modify it.
As the amount of inputs is high (3 prices per tarification, 3 tarifications per area), in order not to rerender everything each time, I'm using useMemo on the function that updates the value of the inputs and aside of this, I'm using useReducer to avoid having a very long code to control inputs.

However, inserting characters (or numbers in this case) in the inputs is not instant as it should be, instead it takes a short time for them to appear, not to mention consecutive inputs.

```
 const handleUpdate = useMemo(
    () => (property, valu, obid) => {
      dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_DATA", property, payload: valu, id: obid });
    },
    [dispatch]
  );
```

And the reducer:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
...
case "UPDATE_DATA":
        return {
          ...state,
          data: state.data.map((item) => {
            if (item.id === action.id) {
              return { ...item, [action.property]: action.payload };
            }
            return item;
          }),
        };
}
}
```

I suggest checking the whole code as the problem (or solution) could be somewhere else. In order to see the whole code, you can refer to this sandcodebox link. Excuse the bad css formating as I copied just some part of it.
Note that the fetch function has been replaced by a long array simulating the data.

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-feynman-g9nox2?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of [`useMemo`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useMemo) generally is to cache the values of expensive calculations done ***during*** rendering. However, in your case, you do not have any expensive rendering calculations; you are just rendering a really large tree every time an input changes. In fact, because all your state is on the `App` component, you rerender the entire app every time.

The way to optimize this in React is to skip rendering components when possible. To do so, split unrelated pieces of the page into distinct components. Once you separate the logic, wrap it with [`React.memo()`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/memo), which is a different optimization technique that can skip the rendering of a component altogether.

To me, the most obvious changes you can make are:

1. Move `TodosDatos` outside the `App` component because it is constant and doesn't need to be redefined on every render (which can be memory-intensive).
2. Move your `<Table>` into a new component that you memoize with `React.memo()`. Make sure to pass all the table's dependency values into the new component's props.

I implemented these changes here: https://codesandbox.io/s/green-breeze-mmum6n?file=/src/App.js. You should notice now that typing is nearly instantaneous. You can probably optimize it in several other places too for even better performance.

Comment: Following your example, it seems I fixed it by using react.memo() on the row component which is in the other file. If you like modify your answer (I'll mark it as accepted) with this: `const FilaMunicipal = React.memo(function(props){
  const { ob, a, handleUpdate } =props ;` Now, I have to read about react.memo as it is completely new concept for me. Thank you!